# How can I let Windows put the monitor to sleep when watching YouTube videos when in full screen mode?

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, sleep, power, youtube

So I like to watch YouTube videos as I fall asleep. It's odd but it's how I am. Anyway I like to watch them in full screen but I want the monitor to turn off after about a minute as I would like my eyes to be better and also I really only care about the audio/background noise.

So, how can I let Windows turn off my monitor (not to sleep or anything like that) while a full screen YouTube video (or really anything in Chrome) is playing?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about how to do that with a delay, but there is a simple way to just turn of your monitor right away:

Go to Power Settings, and open advanced power settings for the plan you are using. Expand "Power Buttons and Lid", and change the Power Button action to "turn off the display". Now whenever you want to turn off the screen, just hit the power button.

Comment: Well I have it set to turn off the monitor after 2 minutes. The problem is it won't if YouTube is playing or in full screen but I WANT IT to.

Comment: This is why, using this method, you can simply turn the monitor off right away instead of waiting for a delay